# Google Map is not loading due to inflate exception

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, fatal-error, inflate-exception

I am using Google Maps v2 in my application. The key is correctly generated, all the permissions exist in manifest. I followed the tutorial of Google Maps v2. I followed each and every step but it's not working. Please Help

Log

```
03-04 01:25:23.145: E/Trace(19467): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps/com.appscourt.jooging.track.map.health.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2136)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2174)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1267)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:260)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1893)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at com.appscourt.jooging.track.map.health.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5058)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    ... 11 more
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4242000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.ex(Unknown Source)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4713)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):    ... 22 more
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private GoogleMap googleMap;
protected LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initializeMap();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    finish();
}

private void initializeMap(){

    if(googleMap == null){

        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.appscourt.jooging.track.map.health.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCV0yduNQJCXrSWNzk6h__6FYaEg_bfCvE"
           />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please show your Manifest

Comment: Add this tag inside application tag in manifest file.  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Answer (score 4):

Your logcat clearly said

```
 03-04 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467): Caused by:
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's
 AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4242000
 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the
 <application> element:     <meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 03-04
 01:25:23.293: E/AndroidRuntime(19467):
```

**Add the Google Play services version to your app's manifest**

> Edit your application's AndroidManifest.xml file, and add the
>   following declaration within the element. This embeds the version of
>   Google Play services that the app was compiled with.

You need to add `<meta-data>` under `<application>` tag into your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
....<application>
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
 </application>
```

This is because latest google play services requires a version name, which is to be mentioned using `<meta-data .. />` inside `AndroidManifest.xml`

and also change `MainActivity` extends `Activity`

For more information go to :[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Comment: What value i should place in android:value?

Comment: @ZiaUrRehman not any value you just put `<meta-data>` tag under `<application>` tag into your `manifest.xml`. it'll take this value from `google_play_services_lib`

Comment: <application>
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 
 </application>  in place of this i use the followiing.....<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCV0yduNQJCXrSWNzk6h__6FYaEg_bfCvE"
           />

Comment: then where i will post API key?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using android-support-v4.jar (for backward support) then try `SupportMapFragment`

replace this line `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`

with  `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

and also put in manifest.xml

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: <meta-data>  tag i hve in manifest file but i added there  an API key ... Can i replace API key on the above meta data....

Comment: you have to use two <meta-data> tag. try updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your package name and the permission tag package names are differing I think and even this `android:name="com.appscourt.jooging.track.map.health.MainActivity"` try to verify